# R predict function and Model Object

Tags: r, machine-learning, predictive-models, prediction

I'm doing machine learning in R. I would like to know how we can create a model object that we can pass to "predict" function along with new data so that we obtain predicted values. 
To elaborate, I'm trying to write a new machine learning algorithm in R. Till now I have only used predict function but don't know how to create "model" objects to pass to predict function. If we're doing a linear regression, calling lm would create "lm" object. If we're doing naiveBayes classifier, and call it from e1071 package, it would create naiveBayes classifier object, which we will pass to predict function. Now, if I'm writing a new algorithm, how do I create an object of that algorithm? And how exactly predict function will process that? What class variables/methods that "model" object should have so that it can be processed by "predict" function available in R? I know this is a bit open ended question, but I couldn't find any proper documentation. A basic/prototype example in terms of code would be highly appreciated. Though I've been using R, I'm not familiar to classes/objects concept in R. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should check out [Hadley Wickham's Advanced R Programming guide](http://adv-r.had.co.nz), especially the part about [object oriented programming in R](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/OO-essentials.html). To provide a couple of useful keywords: you are talking about S3 methods and generic functions.

Basically, `predict` is a generic function, so when you call `predict(obj, data)` for, say, an `lm` model `obj`, R looks through its list of known names to find the function `predict.lm`, which provides thecae necessary to make predictions from an `lm` model.

The model object itself is just a list, with an attribute identifying its class (`lm`, in the example I'm citing). You'll need to return this list from the function that runs your algorithm, via code like

```
result <- list(obj=model, data=data, parameters=params)
class(result) <- 'whatever'
return(result)
```

...or whatever is appropriate output from your algorithm. OK, now you call your function like

```
myobj <- whatever(y~X, data=dat, weights=wt)
```

And finally if you run

```
predict(myobj, newdata, wt.new)
```

R will look for an call your prediction function as

```
predict.whatever(myobj, newdata, wt.new)
```

Read Hadley's page for more details - it can get kind of confusing.

Comment: Thanks so much for the elaborate answer and the link. Will try to understand and get back to you if I've more questions. Just a quick question though - Are you saying we explicitly need to create a function called "predict.whatever"?

Comment: May be it was a stupid question. I think we need to create function "predict.whatever"... how else R would get that..

Comment: Yes you need to write the function predict.whatever yourself. It's first parameter must be the model object (a list with class "whatever"). Good luck!

Comment: Haha, well the only problem is that it was all wrong.